# how to use updated .erlang file without reopening emacs?

Tags: emacs, erlang

In my `.emacs`, It contains the following two parts of codes.

I am debugging two programs together, one is server, and the other is client.

Everytime switching the debuged program, it is necessary to modify the `.erlang` for switching the `code:add_paths` statements and reopening the emacs. (In server and client programs, 3 modules are same, if not switching, the module conflict.

Because reopening emacs is much time-costing ( many files have to be reopened), is it possible for make two `.erlang` file effective with reopening emacs.

```
        (erlang-shell)




    (add-hook 'erlang-mode-hook

          (lambda ()
             (setq inferior-erlang-machine-options '("-name" "emacs"))
            ;(setq inferior-erlang-machine-options '("-name" "emacs""-mnesia dir" 
"/Users/yuchen/Documents
/Project/mnesia_db") )
                 (set (make-local-variable 'compile-command) (format "make -f %s" 
(get-closest-pathname)))
            (imenu-add-to-menubar "imenu")))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to finish your erlang session (switch to `*erlang*` buffer, enter `q().` and press ENTER), edit `~/.erlang` and start erlang again with `erlang-shell`